# After placing text independently in each panel using facet_wrap() , how to change text color in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, geom-text

Here is a data

```
Genotype<- rep(c("CV1","CV2"),each=3)
treatment<-rep(c("T1","T2","T3"),2)
RATIO<- c(0.8,0.7,0.9,1.1,1.0,0.8)
DataA<- data.frame(Genotype,treatment,RATIO)
```

and this is a graph using facet_wrap()

```
A_labels <- data.frame(Genotype=c("CV1", "CV1", "CV1"),
                             perc= c("NA", "NA","PASS"), treatment=c("T1", "T2", "T3"),
                             RATIO=c(1.0, 0.90, 1.0))

B_labels <- data.frame(Genotype=c("CV2", "CV2", "CV2"),
                       perc= c("TEST", "PASS","FAIL"), treatment=c("T1", "T2", "T3"),
                       RATIO=c(1.2, 1.1, 1.1))

ggplot(data=DataA, aes(x=treatment, y=RATIO, fill=treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", width = 0.7) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values= c ("Dark gray","Dark blue", "Dark red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1.5,0.2), labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0,1.5)) +
  
  geom_label(data=A_labels, aes(x=treatment, y=RATIO, label=perc, col=treatment), size=6, fill="white") +
  geom_label(data=B_labels, aes(x=treatment, y=RATIO, label=perc, col=treatment), size=6, fill="white") +
  scale_color_manual(values= c ("Blue","Red", "Blue")) +
  
  labs(x="treatment", y="Ratio (%)") +
  facet_wrap(~Genotype) + 
  theme(axis.title = element_text (face = "plain", size = 20, color = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size= 18),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size= 18),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black"),
        legend.position = 'none')+
  windows(width=9, height=5)
```

[image]

It was successful to place texts in each panel independently using facet_wrap(), but I don't know how to put different color per treatment in each panel independently. For example, in the right panel, I want to change text color as green, yellow and orange.

Due to the code `scale_color_manual(values= c ("Blue","Red", "Blue"))` text color per treatment is the same in both panels.

Could you let me know how to change text color per treatment in each panel independently?

Thanks,

Comment: So, you want to change it only for CV2 but not for CV1, right?

Comment: Yes it is!!! I want to maintain "Blue","Red", "Blue" color in CV1, but change color in CV2 as "green", "yellow" and "orange".

Comment: Do you have these two levels only (that is CV1 and CV2)?

Comment: Yes, I have two levels and divided into two panels using facet_wrap().

Comment: Would you consider creating a new column to represent treatment x genotype, then you can assign a specific color for each combination based on the new column?

Comment: Thank you so much, Ben!! I found the way from your idea!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, you have only two levels. So I would do this a bit differently:

```
#Loading the data and creating the the labels

Genotype<- rep(c("CV1","CV2"),each=3)
treatment<-rep(c("T1","T2","T3"),2)
RATIO<- c(0.8,0.7,0.9,1.1,1.0,0.8)
DataA<- data.frame(Genotype,treatment,RATIO)

A_labels <- data.frame(Genotype=c("CV1", "CV1", "CV1"),
                       perc= c("NA", "NA","PASS"), treatment=c("T1", "T2", "T3"),
                       RATIO=c(1.0, 0.90, 1.0))

B_labels <- data.frame(Genotype=c("CV2", "CV2", "CV2"),
                       perc= c("TEST", "PASS","FAIL"), treatment=c("T1", "T2", "T3"),
                       RATIO=c(1.2, 1.1, 1.1))
```

Now, I will create two separate plots for two levels

```
ggplot(data=subset(DataA, Genotype=='CV1'), aes(x=treatment, y=RATIO, fill=treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", width = 0.7) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values= c ("Dark gray","Dark blue", "Dark red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1.5,0.2), labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0,1.5)) +
  
  geom_label(data=A_labels, aes(x=treatment, y=RATIO, label=perc, col=treatment), size=6, fill="white") +
  scale_color_manual(values= c ("Blue","Red", "Blue")) +
  facet_wrap(~Genotype)+
  labs(x="treatment", y="Ratio (%)") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text (face = "plain", size = 20, color = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size= 18),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size= 18),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black"),
        legend.position = 'none')-> plot_cv1



ggplot(data=subset(DataA, Genotype=='CV2'), aes(x=treatment, y=RATIO, fill=treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", width = 0.7) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values= c ("Dark gray","Dark blue", "Dark red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1.5,0.2), labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0,1.5)) +
  geom_label(data=B_labels, aes(x=treatment, y=RATIO, label=perc, col=treatment), size=6, fill="white") +
  scale_color_manual(values= c ("Green","Yellow", "Orange")) +
  facet_wrap(~Genotype)+
  labs(x="treatment", y="Ratio (%)") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text (face = "plain", size = 20, color = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size= 18),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size= 18),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black"),
        legend.position = 'none')-> plot_cv2
```

Now you may use, `grid.arrange` from `gridExtra` or `ggarrange` from `ggpubr`

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(plot_cv1, plot_cv2, nrow = 1)

#or

library(ggpubr)
ggarrange(plot_cv1, plot_cv2, nrow = 1)
```

Both will have the same output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

I found the way to solve this issue from the Ben's advice above. First we make one combination between 2 factors, and this combination will have 6 levels. (2 Genotype x 3 treatment). Then, in scale_color_manual, we can designate each color about the 6 levels!!

```
#Loading the data and creating the the labels
Genotype<- rep(c("CV1","CV2"),each=3)
treatment<-rep(c("T1","T2","T3"),2)
COMBI<- c("CV1T1","CV1T2","CV1T3","CV2T1","CV2T2","CV2T3")
RATIO<- c(0.8,0.7,0.9,1.1,1.0,0.8)
DataA<- data.frame(Genotype,treatment,COMBI, RATIO)

A_labels <- data.frame(Genotype=c("CV1", "CV1", "CV1"),
                       perc= c("NA", "NA","PASS"), treatment=c("T1", "T2", "T3"),
                       RATIO=c(1.0, 0.90, 1.0))

B_labels <- data.frame(Genotype=c("CV2", "CV2", "CV2"),
                       perc= c("TEST", "PASS","FAIL"), treatment=c("T1", "T2", "T3"),
                       RATIO=c(1.2, 1.1, 1.1))

#GGPLOT
ggplot(data=DataA, aes(x=treatment, y=RATIO, fill=treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", width = 0.7) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values= c ("Dark gray","Dark blue", "Dark red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1.5,0.2), labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0,1.5)) +
  
  geom_label(data=A_labels, aes(x=treatment, y=RATIO, label=perc, col=subset(DataA, Genotype=="CV1")$COMBI), size=6, fill="white") +
  geom_label(data=B_labels, aes(x=treatment, y=RATIO, label=perc, col=subset(DataA, Genotype=="CV2")$COMBI), size=6, fill="white") +
  scale_color_manual(values= c ("Blue","Red","Blue","Green","Yellow", "Orange")) +
  labs(x="treatment", y="Ratio (%)") +
  facet_wrap(~Genotype) + 
  theme(axis.title = element_text (face = "plain", size = 20, color = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size= 18),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size= 18),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "black"),
        legend.position = 'none')+
  windows(width=9, height=5)
```

[image]